# Automating a directory diff while ignoring some particular lines in files

Tags: python, regex, diff, araxis

I need to compare two directories, and produce some sort of structured output (text file is fine) of the differences.  That is, the output might looks something like this:

```
file1 exists only in directory2
file2 exists only in directory1
file3 is different between directory1 and directory2
```

I don't care about the format, so long as the information is there.  The second requirement is that I need to be able to ignore certain character sequences when diffing two files.  Araxis Merge has this ability: you can type in a Regex and any files whose only difference is in character sequences matching that Regex will be reported as identical.

That would make Araxis Merge a good candidate, BUT, as of yet I have found no way to produce a structured output of the diff.  Even when launching consolecompare.exe with command-line argumetns, it just opens an Araxis GUI window showing the differences.

So, does either of the following exist?

- A way to get Araxis Merge to print a diff result to a text file?
- Another utility that do a diff while ignoring certain character
  sequences, and produce structured output?

Extra credit if such a utility exists as a module or plugin for Python.  Please keep in mind this must be done entirely from a command line / python script - no GUIs.

Comment: What happens if you use [`consolecompare`](http://www.araxis.com/merge/command_line.html) instead of `compare`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extent, the plain old `diff` command can do just that, i.e. compare directory contents and ignoring changes that match a certain regex pattern (Using the `-I` option).

From [man bash](http://ss64.com/bash/diff.html):

```
-I regexp
      Ignore changes that just insert or delete lines that match  regexp.
```

Quick demo:

```
[me@home]$ diff images/ images2
Only in images2: x
Only in images/: y
diff images/z images2/z
1c1
< zzz
---
> zzzyy2

[me@home]$ # a less verbose version
[me@home]$ diff -q images/ images2
Only in images2: x
Only in images/: y
Files images/z and images2/z differ

[me@home]$ # ignore diffs on lines that contain "zzz"
[me@home]$ diff -q -I ".*zzz.*" images/ images2/
Only in images2/: x
Only in images/: y
```

Comment: Almost forgot, this is running on windows.

Comment: I'm investigating a bash for windows port, because this looks very enticing!

Comment: MinGW should be able to provide you with a port of bash and all those *nix goodies. And there's also cygwin.